# Database Not Found while using PDO to retrieve data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to retrieve data from mysql database using PDO but "DATABASE NOT FOUND" Output is executing

here is my code

```
<form id="form" action="sum1.php" method="post">
<td><p align="center"> IDNO : <input type="text" name="id" id="id" maxlength="10"></p></td>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" class='btnExample' value="Click here to get your Result">
 </form> 
<?PHP 
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "demo";
$dbuser     = "admin";
$dbpass     = "123456";
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
if ($db_found) {
$id = $_POST['id'];

$add = $db->prepare("SELECT htno, SUM(tm) AS tech FROM hmm WHERE htno > :id");
$add -> execute(array('id'=>$id));
echo " <center><table id='mytable' cellspacing='0'  border=3 align=center> 
<tr><TH scope='col'>Total Marks</TH> </tr><center>"; 
while ($row1 = $add->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<td align=center>" . $row1['tech4']. "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
  }
  }
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
}
$db = null;
?>
```

I am unable to find the error

Please help me

Comment: try change `$dbhost = "localhost";` to ``$dbhost = "localhost:3306";``

Comment: What does `$db_found` do? and where it come from?

Comment: @taiki no its not working, getting additional errors

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Wat should be placed instead of $db_found ??

Comment: @Aryan What is that variable? Where did you declared it? Is it a built in variable?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I Replaced ($db_found) with ($db) , now i am not getting DATABASE NOT FOUND but still the out is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are creating the connection objects with the following statement:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
```

but, for checking it, you have:

```
if ($db_found) {
```

instead, you'll have to use `$db` there. Like this:

```
if ($db) {
```

## Edit

Also, your execute function should read like:

```
$add->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
```

Notice the `:id` instead of `id`.

Comment: thankyou... Now its not showing "DATABASE NOT FOUND" but still iam getting output as blank

Comment: Ya modified but still output is blank :(

Comment: @Aryan You don't have a column named `tech4`. Edit `$row1['tech4']` to `$row1['tech']`.

Comment: Edited but i am getting wrong output, instead of 422 as output i am getting 258633 , for every input i am getting different outputs :(

Comment: @Aryan That can not be answered without having a look at your table and inputs.

Comment: but the same query with same table when i am using mysql queries then its showing me exact output, when i am using PDO its showing incorrect output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18032/discussion-between-aryan-and-the-doctor-from-tardis)